# How can I find out the name, ID, or type of a UITableView Cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if([tableView.somethingMagicalHereThatAllowsMeKnowWhichCellItIs isEqualToString:@"CellType"]){
    return 50;
}
return 25;}
```

I have tableView with multiple cells of different types, and I want to style them accordingly, but the problem is that I don't know which type it is when it comes in.  I can't use indexPath because the cells are in no specific order.  Is there a way to show the id?

Comment: When you implement the data source method -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you do know which cell to display for any given indexPath, right? Why can't you use the same approach in -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is remove the “what goes in which table view cell” from `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and put it in a separate method. How I name this depends on what I’m trying to achieve. One typical scenario is that each cell represents an object. In that case, I define a method like this:

```
- (SomeObject*)objectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

Then, in both `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, I call that method to find out which object corresponds to that cell, then either create the cell or set its height accordingly.